# does redux state change when fetching data and getting back same data?

Tags: redux

In redux, if i fetch data and let s say if i get back the same data, will it trigger componentDidUpdate? Can I assume previous props and current props are not the same even fetch data is same as previous data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

`shouldComponentUpdate`  only uses shallow comparison, which basically does a strict equality check on `props` vs `prevProps`.

What this means is:

If your props (via `mapStateToProps`) are basic types - strings, numbers, booleans - then `componentDidUpdate` will not be called if Redux returns the same values.

If they're complex - Objects, Arrays, etc. - then `componentDidUpdate` will get called, even if the data is the same. This is because `{ foo: 'bar' }` !== `{ foo: 'bar' }`. You could hook into `shouldComponentUpdate` and check the equality yourself to prevent this from happening. For example, you could do something like:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
   if (JSON.stringify(nextProps.foo) === JSON.stringify(this.props.foo)) {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Your actual implementation should take into consideration the other props that may/may not change.